# What is an Exclusive Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the **What is a [Word™](/search?tab=Newest&q=is:question+%22I+call+it%22+title:Word%E2%84%A2)/[Phrase™](/search?tab=Newest&q=is:question+%22I+call+it%22+title:Phrase%E2%84%A2)** series started by [JLee](/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](/search?tab=Newest&q=is:question+phrase+title:%22What+is%22+title:Phrase+user:463) and [Word™](/search?tab=Newest&q=is:question+%22I+call+it%22+title:%22What+is%22+title:Word+user:463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an ***Exclusive Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Exclusive Words™ | Not Exclusive Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BY | NEAR |
| PA | DAD |
| ERR | ERROR |
| LED | LEAD |
| SHY | BOLD |
| ANTE | POST |
| BRED | SIRED |
| BRIG | JAIL |
| DIES | LIVES |
| IRON | STEEL |
| SPIT | SALIVA |
| BLEST | CURSED |
| BRING | LEAVE |
| CLING | CLEAVE |
| COMMS | RADIOS |
| GRADS | STUDENTS |
| HOVER | FLOAT |
| MATED | JOINED |
| MEERS | TARNS |
| STOUT | STURDY |
| HOLLER | SHOUT |
| SHOPPER | CONSUMER |
| REPRIMED | REPAINTED |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Exclusive Words™,Not Exclusive Words™
BY,NEAR
PA,DAD
ERR,ERROR
LED,LEAD
SHY,BOLD
ANTE,POST
BRED,SIRED
BRIG,JAIL
DIES,LIVES
IRON,STEEL
SPIT,SALIVA
BLEST,CURSED
BRING,LEAVE
CLING,CLEAVE
COMMS,RADIOS
GRADS,STUDENTS
HOVER,FLOAT
MATED,JOINED
MEERS,TARNS
STOUT,STURDY
HOLLER,SHOUT
SHOPPER,CONSUMER
REPRIMED,REPAINTED
```

This puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt rule that each word can be tested for whether it is an Exclusive Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Exclusive Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**
**Why are they called Exclusive Words™?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An 'Exclusive Word' is...

> ...a word which can have the substring '**AND**' inserted somewhere among its letters to make another real word.
>
>  All the words on the left satisfy this:
>
>  B**AND**Y
>  P**AND**A
>  ERR**AND**
>  L**AND**ED
>  SH**AND**Y
>  [**AND**ANTE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/andante)
>  BR**AND**ED
>  BRIG**AND**
>  D**AND**IES
>  [**AND**IRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andiron)
>  S**AND**PIT
>  BL**AND**EST
>  BR**AND**ING
>  C**AND**LING
>  COMM**AND**S
>  GR**AND**ADS
>  H**AND**OVER
>  M**AND**ATED
>  ME**AND**ERS
>  ST**AND**OUT
>  HOLL**AND**ER
>  [S**AND**HOPPER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talitridae)
>  REPRIM**AND**ED

The name 'Exclusive Word' suggests a connection with...

> ...the logical operator **[XAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate)**, or '**exclusive and**' (the equivalent of 'XNOR' and logical complement to 'XOR'), since all of these words have *excluded 'AND'*...